# Looking to extract the text from ePubs, but remove the table of contents. Is this possible?

Tags: regex, parsing, language-agnostic, extract, epub

For an application I'm creating, I'm looking to extract the text from open source ePubs, and manipulate the text. However, I don't want the table of contents. I'd just like from Chapter 1 or the Prologue/Preface on.

Take *Tom Sawyer* on Project Gutenberg for example: http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/74

ePubs are pretty much just a ZIP file with a bunch of HTML documents. So I open the first HTML file in that above link after unzipping the ePub, and I get the first chapter as well as a bunch of table of contents that I don't want.

That's where I'm curious. Is it possible, via some metadata that I'm missing, or Regex, to remove the table of contents/detect it?

To be clear, I'm talking programmatically.

Comment: Have you tried Calibre?

Comment: @Antimony Do they have an API? I'm talking programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In epub2, there is a table of contents file. First, start with the container.xml. It is always in the same place with the same name in an ePub.

```
$unzip -p /Users/mwu/Downloads/9781434705211.epub META-INF/container.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<container version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container">
<rootfiles>
    <rootfile full-path="OPS/package.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
</rootfiles>
</container>
```

That tells you that the ePub package metadata is located in OPS/package.opf. The package metadata specifies that there is a manifest of all of the files in the ePub and a spine item listing defining what order they should come in the book. The spine tag also defines where the table of contents is with the toc attribute. Also, the items listed in the spine represent the files that make up the book itself. Anything listed linear="no" is auxiliary content rather than primary content. The specification says that the first linear="yes" (which is the default value) begins the main reading order however that can contain (as is the case in this book) a table of contents as part of the book itself.

```
<manifest>
...
<item id="ncx" href="toc.ncx" media-type="application/x-dtbncx+xml"/>
...
</manifest>
<spine toc="ncx">
<itemref idref="my-html-cover" linear="no"/>
<itemref idref="title"/>
<itemref idref="f1"/>
<itemref idref="ded"/>
<itemref idref="contents"/>
<itemref idref="ack"/>
<itemref idref="f2"/>
<itemref idref="chapter1"/>
<itemref idref="chapter2"/>
<itemref idref="chapter3"/>
<itemref idref="chapter4"/>
<itemref idref="chapter5"/>
<itemref idref="chapter6"/>
<itemref idref="chapter7"/>
<itemref idref="b1"/>
<itemref idref="b2"/>
<itemref idref="b3"/>
<itemref idref="b4"/>
<itemref idref="copyright"/>
</spine>
```

This tells you that the table of contents is idenified by the ncx item in the manifest which references the toc.ncx file. Note that the path is relative to the package.opf file, so it can be found at OPS/toc.ncx

The toc.ncx file contains a navMap tag which lists navPoint tags defining the different parts of the book and references to them.

Both in the <spine> tag in the package.opf file and in the toc.ncx file, you can get a listing of the parts of the book and in what order they go in. They also both list contents.html which I think is what you want to exclude. There is nothing consistent that can identify that in-spine table of contents, nor is it guaranteed to even exist in a book. You can try scanning the spine tag as well as the contents of each spine item file for words that commonly identify a table of contents or for a series of links that reference other spine items in the book, but that may not catch everything 100% of the time.

Generally, files like that are considered part of the book and removing them is considered incorrect (accessibility is one of the bigger reasons why).

Also, note that the ePub 2 file specifications can be found at http://idpf.org/epub/201. The ePub 3 specifications are at http://idpf.org/epub/30

Comment: Thinking about this again, I think I would parse the html in the spine items and look for anchor tags referencing other spine items. A series of these would likely identify a table of contents.

Comment: In the ncx file it references the #id of the table of contents in the HTML DOM. Would that be eht best bet?

Comment: It looks like in this case, it does list the TOC in the ncx (a reference in the guide section of the opf file also points out the TOC: <reference href="@public@vhost@g@gutenberg@html@files@74@74-h@74-h-0.htm.html#pgepubid00002" type="toc" title="CONTENTS"/>). I don't think ePubs are required to provide those references, so looking for that would work in some ePubs and not others. It is a good starting point, but you would have to have a fallback method of detecting a table of contents within the content of the book.

Comment: I would say a fairly solid algorithm finding the toc within the contents of a book would be to 1: Check the ncx (epub 2) or toc xhtml file (epub 3) for entries named contents (case insensitive compare). 2: Check for entries in the guide in the OPF file for references with type="toc". 3: Fall back to searching through spine items using regular expressions similar to those suggested by the other answers here. Also note that not all ePubs will contain an in-content toc -- they may rely on the epub-specific toc file.

Comment: I don't think it's as simple of a solution as you were hoping for, but I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose you can try something like pulling out `PREFACE` and everything after it:

```
~.*\KPREFACE\n(.*)$~ms
```

This expression matches anything up to `PREFACE` and then forgets it.  Then it matches `PREFACE` followed by a newline and anything after it all the way up to the end.

I get the feeling, though, that you may want the stuff before the table of contents as well.  In that case, you can so something like this to grab the parts before and after the match:

```
~(.*)(?:CONTENTS\n.*?\n{3,})(.*)~ms
```

This would capture everything before the `CONTENTS` and store it into `\1`. Everything after it would be stored in `\2`.

In PHP, I'd use `preg_replace` to put the parts before and after the table of contents together.

```
<?php

$string = preg_replace('~(.*)(?:CONTENTS\n.*?\n{3,})(.*)~ms', '$1$2', $string);
print $string;
```

[Here is a working demo](http://ideone.com/X1s56r)

Answer (score 0):

While I would personally not recommend a string-based approach whenever a DOM-based approach is possible, I don't see a DOM-based possible in this case.

I was able to achieve the desired result in 2 lines of JavaScript code which you can test within your browser console.

```
var dbody = document.body;
dbody.innerHTML = "<h2>" + dbody.innerHTML.substring(dbody.innerHTML.indexOf("PREFACE"));
```

This code should remove everything within the document body before the PREFACE.

Answer (score -1):

how about using sed: `sed '2,/PREFACE/d' fileName > newFile`
or if you want to keep the "Preface" intact `sed '2,/PREFACE/{/PREFACE/n;d}' inputFile > new file`
or even better `sed '/CONTENTS/,/PREFACE/{/PREFACE/n;d}'  fileName > newFile`